# Setting response HEAD 200 OK HTTP/2.0

Tags: php, ajax, header, response, http2

I am trying to set a HEAD response 200 OK in **PHP** with a **AJAX** call.

The weird thing is that on **HTTP** i'll get a response 200 OK but when i run it on SSL i don't get any response.

I tried setting these things in **PHP**:

`header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");` OR `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");` OR `header("HTTP/2.0 200 OK");` AND also `http_response_code (200);`

My **AJAX** call is pretty straight forward:

```
function preloadAudio() {
   $.ajax({
   type: "HEAD",
   async: true,
   url: url
 });
}
```

How can i get a response on HTTP/2 ?
Hope you guys know a solutio.

Comment: Does the response stay completely empty? Are you sure there are no SSL errors?

Comment: The response stays empty. I'm testing it at multaps.com. its a blank page but when you inspect it and head to network tab you will see that the status is empty.